# How to find all occurance of substring in string to set in listview

Tags: java, android

I am unable to get read data of every index.As I Toast fstr it shows last index value.Can any solve my issue

```
            String item=hello$123$gift@hii$150$teddy
            Model model=new Model();
            String[] item=foodItem.split("@");
            for (int i=0; i<item.length; i++){
                String[] perItem=item[i].split("\\$");
                String fstr = perItem[0];
                model.setFood(fstr);
                model.setPrice(perItem[1]);
                model.setQuantity(perItem[2]);
                dataModels.add(model);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You can use textview.append(CharSequence text); to update the string in textview.

Comment: append just add text together in same row. I want to create list view with dynamic data

Comment: Before quesions for textview. If you want listview add relevant code and tell me exact issues.

Comment: I imagine this code would not compile, since the first line is missing quotes around the string.

Answer (score 0):

From your title as stated,
if you want to append the text inside a single textview after splitting them,
you can do it this way

Create a single textview

textview.setText(model.getFood()+model.getPrice()+model.getQuantity())

Comment: But when I set Text, it read only last index that means last item set in textView.

Comment: Where are you passing the list to adapter? Refer https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ for proper recyclerview implementation